# Spring expression languague - determine if servletContext variable is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

In a spring context xml file, I am using a spring EL expression to load a properties file differently based on whether the servletContext predefined variable is null or not.  Below is the Spel expression (formatted for readability):

```
#{
  systemProperties['my.properties.dir'] != null ?
    'file:' + systemProperties['my.properties.dir'] + '/' :
    (servletContext != null ? 
      'file:/apps/mydir' + servletContext.getContextPath() + '/' :
      'classpath:')
}my.properties
```

When I run in a web application, everything is fine.  However, when I run in a standalone application (meaning the servletContext predefined variable is not defined), I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 109): Field or property 'servletContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

Is there a way to determine if servletContext exists?  Or some way to avoid the exception when it is not defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to evaluate the presence, or not, of the bean; you can't just test if it's null because that attempts to use the bean, which doesn't exist.

The `#root` object for the evaluation is a `BeanExpressionContext`.

This should head you in the right direction...

```
<bean id="foo" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="#{containsObject('bar') ? bar : 'foo'}" />
</bean>

<bean id="bar" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="bar" />
</bean>
```

So you would use...

`#{containsObject('servletContext') ? ... servletContext.contextPath ... : ...`

Note that you **can** "reference" the bean in the value part of the ternary expression (when the boolean part evaluates to true), you just can't reference it in the boolean part.